# What is the Angular 2 way of dealing with 3rd party components that do not support Model Driven Forms?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives, angular2-forms, primeng

So I am using Angular 2 to implement a form. This form uses `input` components which is nicely supported by `angular-forms`. I also have components from a 3rd party (PrimeNG) that do not support model-driven forms yet (PickList and DataTable).

My understanding is that if your component only supports model-driven forms if they implement the `ControlValueAccessor` interface.

At the moment I am ignoring those components as part of the form and I merge those values with the `ngForm.value` object on the submit function. This feels very hacky to me and requires two different thought patterns in one form component. The validation here is also really messy and confusing.

The question is what is the **preferred angular 2 way** for dealing with forms when your 3rd party components does not support `angular-forms`/`ngModel`?

Comment: You can wrap the component with your own that actually implements `ControlValueAccessor`.